# Label inside TabStripItem is displayed with capital letters on IOS devices

Tags: angular, tabs, nativescript

I have a strange issue, I'm using a TabStrip in Nativecsript :

```
 <Tabs selectedIndex="0">
            <TabStrip>
                <TabStripItem (tap)="itemTap(0)" >
                    <Label class="{{selectedItem === 0 ? 'tab-active': 'tab-inactive'}}" 
                        text="test1"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem class="special" (tap)="itemTap(1)" >
                    <Label class="{{selectedItem === 1 ? 'tab-active': 'tab-inactive'}}" 
                        text="test2"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
                <TabStripItem class="special" (tap)="itemTap(2)" >
                    <Label class="{{selectedItem === 2 ? 'tab-active': 'tab-inactive'}}" 
                        text="test3"></Label>
                </TabStripItem>
            </TabStrip>
```

I tried adding css text-transform: capitalize option for the label, it works on Android but not on IOS ,
Example :
Android :   Test1.  Test2.  Test3
IOS:        TEST1.  TEST2.  TEST3

Any suggestions?

Comment: TabStripItems can not be stylied individually on ios

Comment: Hi @Yong, so how can I make the text appear capitalized ?

Comment: Tabs has not supported it for now. You can implement customised ActionBar and hide Tabs TabStripItems for workaround.

Comment: Thank you @Yong, can you provide an example or a way to do it. I'm still a beginner in Nativescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of searching, I found that text-transform="capitalize" is not supported by Nativescript, the only way to do so is to add textTransform="none" to the TabStrip.